How to compile files in different directory in c++?
I'm doing a more complex project in c++, but this example here is the same for what i need and the names of examples will just changed, but, again, is the same thing from what i am doing. Let's say I have this file structure:
|--project/
|--main.cpp
|--include/
|      |--class1.hpp
|      |--class2.hpp
|--impl/
|      |--class1.cpp
|      |--class2.cpp


Class2 has a class1 dependency.
class1.hpp
#ifndef CLASS1_HPP
#define CLASS1_HPP

class class1 {
private: string name;
}

#endif

class2.hpp
#ifndef CLASS2_HPP
#define CLASS2_HPP

#include "class1.hpp"

class class2 {
private: Class1 class1;
}

#endif

class1.cpp
#include "class1.hpp"
#include <iostream>

(functions implemantations...)

}

class2.cpp
#include "class2.hpp"
#include "class1.hpp"
#include <iostream>

(functions implemantations...)

}

main.cpp
#include "class2.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    Class2 class2;
    (...)
    return 0;
}

That is, my .hpp and .cpp are in different directories, how can I compile classes in different directories?

Use automation tool like cmake etc.

Ok! Have you some link to help me read more about this? And if I want compile in terminal? what i use for?

Cmake: A Basic Starting Point. There are also books and tutorials on the subject "cmake"

" how can I compile classes in different directories?..." If you're not using say cmake etc then you can also compile multiple files from a particular directory at once. Like g++ *.cpp -o output. See Using G++ to compile multiple .cpp and .h files. But I would highly recommend using cmake etc to do this automatically.

"And if I want compile in terminal? what i use for?" I usually use CMake from the terminal.

Regardless of what automation tool, you use there are two things you need to address  (1)  compiling, so that each #include directive unambiguously resolves to the correct header.  All command line compilers, IDEs, and relevant automation tools support an option to specify an "include path" (and the same include path must be used when compiling every source file).   It is also necessary to either ensure all object files can be found when linking, either by specifying a path for linking (where to look for objects) or by referring to complete names of object files/libraries when linking.

Just compile from terminal
See the g++ command help:
gcc -help | grep " \-I"
  -I-                     Restrict all prior -I flags to double-quoted inclusion and remove current directory from include path
  -I <dir>                Add directory to the end of the list of include search paths

You can just compile your code like this:
g++ -Wall -Iinclude main.cpp impl/class1.cpp impl/class2.cpp -o project

The shown command means:

Enable all warnings
when searching for included headers, the compiler should search not only in system include dirs, but also in include
add all source files
output the executable named project

But this is too complicated, especially when you need to compile to test multi-times.
Use an automation tool
Generally speaking, there are 2 choices: make and cmake
For your understanding, the following solutions are the simplified solution, but not really elegant
Make
all: main.o class1.o class2.o
    gcc -Wall main.o class1.o class2.o -o project

main.o: main.cpp
    gcc -c -Wall main.cpp -o main.o

class1.o: impl/class1.cpp
    gcc -c -Wall -Iinclude impl/class1.cpp -o class1.o

class2.o: impl/class2.cpp
    gcc -c -Wall -Iinclude impl/class2.cpp -o class2.o

clean:
    rm -f project main.o class1.o class2.o

Put this under your project dir, name it Makefile, and run: make
❯ make
gcc -c -Wall main.cpp -o main.o
gcc -c -Wall -Iinclude impl/class1.cpp -o class1.o
gcc -c -Wall -Iinclude impl/class2.cpp -o class2.o
gcc -Wall main.o class1.o class2.o -o project

A executable named project will show, you can run make clean to remove all .o files and your project executable file.
CMake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(project)

add_executable(project 
  main.cpp
  impl/class1.cpp 
  impl/class2.cpp
)
target_include_directories(project PRIVATE include)

Put this in project dir and name it CMakeLists.txt. Run:
cmake -B build # This generate a build dir under `project` dir and names it `build`
cmake --build build # This builds your project

Your executable file will be placed under build dir
